# Rmarkdown: table header only on the first page

Tags: r-markdown, flextable

The header of the Flextable is repeated when the Flextable spans across two pages. I want the header to appear only on the first page.

Any suggestion?

Thank you for your help.

`title: ".."`

`author: ".."`

`date: "xxxx-xx-xx"`

`output: word_document`

`---`

```` ```{r setup, include = FALSE} ````

`knitr::opts_chunk$set(`
`echo = FALSE,`
`message = FALSE,`
`warning = FALSE`
`)`

`library(flextable)`

`library(officedown)`

```` ```{r cars, tab.cap="Header cars table"} ````

`cars |>`
`head(25) |>`
`flextable()`

Answer (score 0):

in 2019, the author of the package answered as
["no option for that"](https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/160).

I still use (in word document)
table properties -> row -> uncheck "Repeat as header row at the top of each page".